# IPsec VPN Tunnel Through an Uncontrolled Network

Tags: vpn, ipsec, tunnel

I'm trying to figure out how to setup multiple IPsec VPN tunnels, and before I spend any money on hardware, I want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly.

My plan is to setup a Vyatta Core server with a static IP address to be one endpoint of the IPsec VPN.  Then, I will have 2 Cisco RV042's in different locations that will connect with the Vyatta server.  Theoretically, I think this should be fine.  The problem is the Cisco RV042's will have Dynamic IP addresses.  One of them will be behind multiple layers of NAT and behind a firewall, which I will have no access to change settings on.

Is this going to work?  If not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPSEC with nat-traversal turned on (upd header added) works with most setups simmilar yours. Depending on the firewall settings, this might also be blocked/disallowed, so there is no way to know without knowing the firewall setting.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have access to the NAT_Firewall this will not work. Presumably that firewall will SNAT, still you need a DNAT for ISAKMP connection.

A solution that probably will work would be to have two Cisco devices and use Cisco Easy VPN, one device acting as a simple client behind the NAT_Firewall.

The cheapest devices would be some 88x, 89x Cisco routers with Security License enabled.

Comment: Not sure about alternative options but we use ASA 5520 at HQ with 20+ ASA 5505s as Easy VPN clients and it works great through multiple layers of NAT in between.